# AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'chroot'

Tags: python, python-3.x, attributeerror, chroot

Below is my very basic code running in spyder & python is choking, what am I doing wrong?

```
import csv,os,sys
path = os.getcwd()
print (path)
os.chroot(path)
```

I get following error message:

```
  os.chroot(path)

AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'chroot'
```

Comment: are you on windows? the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chroot) is only available on unix so it doesn't exist on windows.

Answer (score 3):

One possibility is that your operating system is Microsoft Windows, for which [`os.chroot()` is not available](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chroot).

Comment: yes I am using microsoft windows. I am surprised why spyder did not show me right methods to use based on my operating system

Thanks though used chdir method for changing directory & problem solved.

Ashay

Answer (score 1):

Did you name your file `os.py`? If you did, it is shadowing the stdlib os module. Change the name of your file and delete `os.pyc` or `__pycache__`.

Do `print os` or similar inside the script to see the file path Python is using to get the `os` module.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your code, and there is no any ERROR
but i see this message:
`PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/home/beenj/Documents'` 
means we must run `python3` with `sudo` ==> `sudo python3`
then enter above code...
or run compiled Python application (after completing ) in **S**uper**U**ser**DO** (**sudo**)